# Accurate delays between notes when synthesising a song

Tags: c++, audio, sleep, midi

I'm writing C++ code which plays both digital audio (synthesised music) and MIDI music at the same time (using the RtMidi library.)  The digitised music will play out of the computer's audio device, but the MIDI music could play out of an external synthesiser.  I want to play a song that uses both digitised instruments and MIDI instruments, and I am not sure of the best way to synchronise these two audio streams:

- It is not possible to use a function like Sleep() as the delay time is both uneven and too long for my needs (which are on the order of one millisecond.)  If Sleep() regularly waits for 5ms when only 1ms was requested, the resulting song tempo will be off, and unless it's exact each time it's called, the tempo will be uneven.
- Counting the number of samples placed into the audio buffer provides super accurate timing between notes for the digital audio (minimum delay of one sample - 0.02ms at 48kHz), but this timing can't be used for MIDI.  Because the audio is buffered the notes are synthesised in bursts (filling up one audio buffer at a time, as quickly as possible) so this results in a bunch of MIDI notes being played with no delay between them every time a digital audio buffer needs to be refilled.
- Playing live MIDI data has no timing information, so a note plays as soon as it is sent.  Therefore a note can't be scheduled to play at a later time, so I am required to accurately send MIDI events at the correct time myself.

Currently I am using nanosleep() - which only works under Linux, not Windows - to wait for the correct time between notes.  This allows both the digital audio and the MIDI data to remain synchronised, however nanosleep() is not very consistent so the resulting tempo is very uneven.

Can anyone think of a way to retain accurate timing between notes for both the digital audio as well as the MIDI data?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use Boost, it has [CPU-precision timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html). If not, on Windows there are functions [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, which can be used for CPU-based timing, which will certainly suit all of your needs. There are plenty of Timer classes implementations around the web, some of them working both on windows and *ix systems.

Comment: This certainly seems to give me accurate timing (at the expense of increased CPU usage.)  I am able to get to within around 500 nanoseconds.  Unfortunately I now encounter another problem - I can send the events at the correct time, but my audio buffer is ~60ms long, so I still cannot get notes played at times that are not multiples of 60ms!

Comment: If you can allow for a bit of delay when playing, you could use larger buffers and pre-create the sounds before playing. If you hold the playback of the streamed file, you will be able to put notes in the buffer accordingly.

Comment: I am thinking about this, but trying to hold back the buffer (without getting underrun) is going to be difficult.  I am thinking I might have to run the digital and MIDI clocks independently, and synchronise them periodically to avoid too much drift.

Comment: I really think you should state/decide if your application will be going live, or rather will be used in production/home environment. Even professional audio workstations tell you it's the tradeoff between quality(in your case, precision) and latency.

Comment: The intended purpose is for home users to preview a song while making changes to it.  The latency doesn't matter that much (if it takes a second or two for changes to take effect that's acceptable) but the precision needs to be high enough that the tempo sounds stable.  Right now it is very obviously playing at an uneven speed.

Comment: Ok, so don't try to play a note as soon as you get the event. Render it/put into buffer instead with correct offset and then feed the buffer (which should be properly synchronized now) together with the background audio. Without looking at the code, which I presume can't / don't want to send I'am afraid I won't be able to help you much more.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you need to know how much audio has passed through the audio device. If your latency is low enough, you might be able to hazard a guess from the amount of data you've pushed through, but the latency between that and the playback is a moving target, so you should try to get that information from the audio hardware. That information is available, so use it because the "jitter" you will get from errors in latency measurement can effect the synchronization in a musically noticeable way.

If you must use sleep for timing, there are two issues that will make it sleep longer: 1. priority (if another process/thread has higher priority, it will run if if the timer has run out) and 2. system latency (if the system takes 5 milliseconds to swap processes/threads, it might add that to your requested delay time). These kinds of delays are musically relevant. Most midi APIs have a "sequencer" api that lets you queue data in advance to avoid having to use system timers.

You might find this document useful, even if you are not using portaudio for audio I/O.

http://www.portaudio.com/docs/portaudio_sync_acmc2003.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this lies not in small buffers, but in large ones.

Let's take an example of a 3-minute song.

One first renders the digital part, and "tags" it with MIDI notes.
Then one starts it playing and triggers the MIDI notes when it's time, perhaps using an std::vector to hold an in-order list.
The synchronization can be changed by using an overall time offset:

HORRIBLE incomplete but hopefully demonstrative pseudocode on the topic:

```
start_digital_playing_thread();
int midi_time_sync = 10; // ms
if (time >= (midi_note[50]->time + midi_time_sync)) // play note
```

Comment: The problem here is that because of the way the audio output works (think double-buffered), it happens in bursts as each buffer empties and the next one is refilled ASAP.  Imagine in your example above, `time` increasing in units of 50ms.  This means that it's not possible to delay less than 50ms between notes, resulting in an uneven tempo.  I need some way of incrementing `time` more accurately.

Comment: @Malvineous I'm sorry but as far as I understand it, if you're simply playing a digital file in the background, you should have no trouble firing off MIDI notes at the correct times. If you're restricted to single threading, how long does it take to fill the buffer if it's already rendered? The MIDI and digital have separate clocks - the digital buffer is filled independently of the MIDI signals which are only synced. Like audio and video.

Comment: @stdorgnldave: I am synthesising the digital audio stream on-the-fly from a series of note events.  Some notes go to the digital stream and some go to a MIDI interface.  Firing MIDI notes at the correct time doesn't seem to be a problem any more (thanks to Bartek Banachewicz's suggestion of boost::timer) but I can't use this method to play the digital notes due to the size of the output audio buffer.  It seems I may have to play the digital stream ~60ms early using a different timer, to counteract the effect of the output buffer introducing a variable 0-60ms latency on each digital note.